# Launching two goroutines in parallel and returning result of the first finished

Tags: go, concurrency, timeout

Real case: I need to retrieve data from a web service (main process), but in case that web service is taking too long, I retrieve the data from the cache (that data might be older) in a parallel process (alt process). If the main process completes first, I return that data. If the main process doesn't complete before the timeout, then the alt process returns either the data (if alt process has completed) or a default value, if alt process hasn't completed by the timeout.

I have built the function that provides the generic capability, but I am not sure if it's the best way to implement the logic.

```
package common

import (
    "time"
)

// Function launches the race between mainFunc and mainFunc, with a cutoff timeout
// If mainFunc finishes before the timeout, its result is sent to chResult
// If timeout is triggered before mainFunc is complete, then:
//      If altFunc is complete by then, its result is sent to chResult
//      Otherwise, defaultResult is sent to chResult
func LaunchRace[T any](chResult chan T, delayTimeout time.Duration, mainFunc func(chan T), altFunc func(chan T), defaultResult T) {
    go func(ch chan T) {
        mainFunc(ch)
    }(chResult)

    go func(ch chan T) {
        chTimeout := time.After(delayTimeout)

        ch1 := make(chan T)
        go func() {
            altFunc(ch1)
        }()

        result := defaultResult

        for {
            select {
            case result = <-ch1:
                continue
            case <-chTimeout:
                ch <- result
                return
            }
        }

    }(chResult)
}
```

And some unit tests for it:

```
package common

import (
    "testing"
    "time"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

type Delay struct {
    DelayMain time.Duration
    DelayAlt  time.Duration
    Timeout   time.Duration
}

func Scenario(t *testing.T, delay Delay, chResult chan string) {
    LaunchRace(chResult, delay.Timeout,
        func(ch chan string) {
            time.Sleep(delay.DelayMain)
            ch <- "main"
        }, func(ch chan string) {
            time.Sleep(delay.DelayAlt)
            ch <- "alt"
        }, "default")
}

func TestMain(t *testing.T) {
    delay := Delay{
        DelayMain: 1 * time.Second,
        DelayAlt:  2 * time.Second,
        Timeout:   3 * time.Second,
    }

    chResult := make(chan string)
    Scenario(t, delay, chResult)
    result := <-chResult
    assert.Equal(t, "main", result)
}

func TestAlt(t *testing.T) {
    delay := Delay{
        DelayMain: 10 * time.Second,
        DelayAlt:  1 * time.Second,
        Timeout:   2 * time.Second,
    }

    chResult := make(chan string)
    Scenario(t, delay, chResult)
    result := <-chResult
    assert.Equal(t, "alt", result)
}

func TestDefault(t *testing.T) {
    delay := Delay{
        DelayMain: 10 * time.Second,
        DelayAlt:  2 * time.Second,
        Timeout:   1 * time.Second,
    }

    chResult := make(chan string)
    Scenario(t, delay, chResult)
    result := <-chResult
    assert.Equal(t, "default", result)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### General comments

- You don't need to pass in the channel as a parameter to the goroutine. Take a look at [closures](https://gobyexample.com/closures). Therefore,

```golang
go func(ch chan T) {
   mainFunc(ch)
}(chResult)
```

changes to

```golang
go mainFunc(ch)
```

- In Go, if your function parameters have the same type consecutively, you can omit all of them except the last one. So this,

```golang
func(int1 int, string1 string, string2 string, int2 int) {}
```

will become this:

```golang
func(int1 int, string1, string2 string, int2 int) {}
```

#### context.Context

You can make this code more idiomatic by using Go's `context.Context` [package](https://pkg.go.dev/context).

The package contains a handy [WithTimeout](https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithTimeout) function. The Context type contains a `Done` channel that is closed whenever the deadline expires.

How does the program with `context` work?

- Your function now accepts a `context.Context` as an argument. It's idiomatic to put it as the very first argument. It's convention to use `ctx` as the variable name.

```
func LaunchRaceWithContext[T any](ctx context.Context) T  {

}
```

- Your main and cache functions, instead of taking a channel, return the type. Remember, channels are cheap.

```golang
func LaunchRaceWithContext[T any](ctx context.Context, mainFn, cacheFn func() T) {

}
```

- You create 2 new channels, one that will receive from the main function and another from the cache function.

```golang
mainCh := make(chan T)
cacheCh := make(chan T)
```

- Start the goroutines.

```golang
go func() {
   mainCh <- mainFn()
}()
go func() {
   cacheCh <- cacheFn()
}()
```

- We will use Go's [select](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/5) statement to wait for whichever channel returns the value first.

```golang
var result T  // default value
select {
   case result = <-mainCh:
   case result = <-cacheCh:
   case <- ctx.Done()
}

return result
```

Above, we default construct T, and wait for whichever channels complete first. If the operation times out, the `ctx.Done` channel will close which means the default value will be returned. Otherwise, `result` will contain the value returned by either the main function or cache function.

- On the caller side, we create a context with the desired timeout.

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5 * time.Second)
defer cancel()
```

- and pass it to the function.

```
result := LaunchRaceWithContext(ctx, mainFn, cacheFn)
```

The entire code looks like this:

```golang
func LaunchRaceWithContext[T any](ctx context.Context, mainFn, cacheFn func() T) T {
    mainCh := make(chan T)
    cacheCh := make(chan T)

    go func() {
        mainCh <- mainFn()
    }()

    go func() {
        cacheCh <- cacheFn()
    }()

    var res T
    select {
    case res = <-mainCh:
    case res = <-cacheCh:
    case <-ctx.Done():
    }
    return res
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    mainFn := func() string {
        time.Sleep(8 * time.Second)
        return "main"
    }

    cacheFn := func() string {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
        return "cache"
    }

    res := LaunchRaceContext(ctx, mainFn, cacheFn)
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```